# How @Counted works in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring, spring-micrometer

How @Counted works?
I have added @Counted annotation on my method in Controller and expecting to see how many hits are coming to the controller. But i cannot see metrics added onto the url http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus.

```
 @Counted(value = "counted.success.test",description = "testCounter")
```

Comment: Can you please provide what all configuration you did for prometheus to divert all the stats to the actuator?

Are you getting the key in actuator or not?

Comment: @Yogesh Prajapati was not getting the key in prometheus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a `CountedAspect` as a bean, then the metrics are created when you call the method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class Config {

    @Bean
    CountedAspect countedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new CountedAspect(registry);
    }
```

(Can't remember why we added the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`)

Though that that kind of instumentation is not prefect, the labels `class` and `method` will change as soon as you refactor your code and your Grafana dashboard might not work any longer.

Comment: Added bean of CountedAspect and it worked.                                                             
    @Bean
    public CountedAspect countedAspect(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        return new CountedAspect(meterRegistry);
    }

Comment: I also had to add this dependeny   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>

Comment: Can this metric be used to display the number of counts over the time (and how)? Or can I only display a total count in Grafana?